# How to create Motion Trail in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I want to create a motion trail effect for a sword like known in games look at that example if you have an solution that looks not as fancy as in the picture don't mind to post it. I'll accept anything useful.

[image]

Comment: Just an idea: How about emitting glowing particles from the sword while it is swung?

Comment: There is an experimental adon called motion trails. Its for blender internal but the materials can be tweaked for cycles. It doesn't work on 2.73 but it might work on older versions

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is what I achieved using transparent nodes and AnimAll addon.
[image]

Create a plane and give it a 'slashy' shape. Add a curve and place a mesh along it using a *Curve Modifier*. Add a *Subsurf Modifier* also if you like.
[image]

Prepare two textures- a color map texture (in this case I used a hair photo) and a mask texture (a simple oblong b&w gradient image).
[image]

Create two *UV Maps*- first for a color texture and second for a mask (which will be helpful in achieving the fading effect). Unwrap the mesh using *Project from View (Bounds)*. Scale the island of the second UV map as shown below.
[image]

Set up the nodes as pictured below. We want to use the color texture for the emission color and as a mask for a transparency. Optional you may add an extra overall transparency to the mesh (just add one more transparency node and mix it with existing nodes).
[image]

Now we'll set up an oblong gradient texture as a mask for a fading effect.
[image]

Place the uv island as pictured below, enable the ***AnimAll Addon*** and check the UVs box . Go to the desired start frame and insert a keyframe. Next, place the uv island in the dark part of a gradient texture. Go to another chosen frame and insert a keyframe again. Play the animation in *Object Mode* and you'll see the fading effect.
[image]

Here is the same animation as on top, but with less transparency and played slower.
[image]

Here's the .blend file: [image]

Comment: looks great dude gonna try this.

Comment: Great! It's much more efficient than particles system. Is it possible to use this texture along a parametrized path or a curve ?

Comment: @PaulGonet could you link slash texture ?

Comment: @vejn I just modified a simple hair texture from net. But if you haven't got time for that I posted a .blend file, which contains all packed textures. Download it, open, then go to File-->External Data-->Unpack All Into Files-->Use files in current directory. This will create a folder with all the textures you need.

Comment: @PaulGonet ,thank you. Could  you look into http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42731/creating-wisp-materials-in-cycles and give me an insight or idea how to start.