# Is it possible to animate textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, transforms

How can I animate a texture?

I don't want to animate an object with a texture on it, but instead, animate the texture itself and have the UV move. If the UV moves, the texture will change live. This is what I am going for.

Comment: @brasshat Maybe you should explain that a bit better? It seems like you tried linking to something and it didn't show up.

Comment: You're right, Tardis, I was in a hurry again, but I didn't try linking in the comment. Nomar, first, welcome to the site. Next, in Neil Hirsig's Blender course at <gryllus.net/Blender/3D.html>, the eighth video tutorial in lesson 8 covers the displacement modifier. 1' 13" seconds into the tutorial, Neil advocates, and shows how to, attach a texture to an empty Blender object for use with the displacement modifier. I believe you could also attach the animated texture to an empty object in the same manner.

Answer (score 9):

Almost any value in blender can be animated. Most of the values that can't be animated are global to the scene like render resolution that make no sense to animate.

With the cursor over a value press <kbd>I</kbd> to add a keyframe or right click <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and choose `Insert Keyframe`, even values in the node editor and colours can be animated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Animating mapping node for some reason does not produce any updates in the viewport though...

Answer (score 8):

One way this can be done, is by animating the **offset sliders** in the *Textures Panel*. Simply hover with cursor over *X,Y,Z values* (see the image below) and press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe:

[image]

Comment: Related answer, that uses Mutant Bob's method: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40085/how-to-animate-texture-change-in-blender-internal and

Comment: Just a comment, this is the fastest way to achieve some translation of the texture inside a mesh, the fact is that it wont show on the viewport this translation (using BI) I don´t know how it works now on Eevee.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **UV Warp** modifier to offset UVs:

[image]

It takes 2 objects (or also bones) to define the transformation. You can easily:

- rotate
- translate
- scale the UV

and also set the center point of transformation.

It allows you to also input vertex map to limit the influence of modifier.

Comment: Cool answer. Especially due to the fact that the modifier can be tied to a rig, which would need a lot more work to do, using material nodes afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the ***AnimAll*** add on to do it. Go to *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and activate it.
[image]

Here are some examples how to use it:

- [How do you animate image texture materials in blender cycles with keyframes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes)
- [Animating eye texture in a head mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh)
- [How to create Motion Trail in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative procedural way is to get time value with attribute nodes and calculate uv location from that. This is more complicated, but useful for example to making reusable animator node groups.

[image: Animate UV Map X Location]