# How do you animate image texture materials in blender cycles with keyframes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, image, keyframes

I have an image texture material on a mesh already in blender cycles 2.75... I was wondering how to change the material with keyframes so it changes to different pictures in the animation... I tried image sequence, but that doesn't seem to be what I am trying to achieve, neither does pressing "i" on the image source in the materials tab, it just says that the name property can not be animated ... Could someone help?

Comment: Have you tried the AnimAll add-on? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSTp8EXSYnk, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlJ71XChDuY

Comment: No I haven't.... I will see if it is what i am looking for... Thank you Very much!

Comment: Give it a try. Using it you may easily animate the textures. It works both in BI and Cycles. Here's an example how it works: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh

Comment: Thank You very much! Your help was very much appreciated!

Comment: @cegaton your wish is my command :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can animate textures using the ***AnimAll*** addon.
[image]

Enable the addon (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>*-->Add-ons*-->***AnimAll***).
[image]

Unwrap your mesh (<kbd>U</kbd>*-->Unwrap*). In *UV Editor* open your texture.
[image]

Check the ***UVs*** box in the *AnimAll* panel. Go to the frame you like and place the *UV island* in *UV Editor* wherever you like (enable the *magnet icon* and set its type to *Increment* to move it precisely). Now press ***Insert*** button as pictured below.
[image]

Then go to another frame, change the position of the *UV island* and press ***Insert*** again.
[image]

Here are my other answers that uses an ***Animall*** adon, that may help you:

- [How to create Motion Trail in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles)
- [Animating eye texture in a head mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh/18484#18484)
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35887/how-to-create-and-apply-a-moving-texture

Comment: Ok! Very nice answer! but what if i want to use it to make my character switch facial expressions (My Character is just a basic UV sphere)... i made a strip of facial expressions on GIMP, and then put it into blender on the sphere using and image texture material, then used the UV image editor, placed the island on the face that I want to be shown on the front side of the sphere.. But it shows all the faces i made for the sphere... is there a way where i can show just one face on one side of the sphere without showing any other ones?

Comment: Just scale the unwrapped UV island and fit the texture by scaling it in UV Editor. I show how to do exactly what you want step by step here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh/18484#18484 See the cegaton's answer there also, as his method is different from mine, but very smart and useful.

Answer (score 14):

To dissolve one image into another, connect the different image textures to a color mix node, before the shader node.
By animating the Mix Factor you can control the how the images change.

[image]

Cascading this node setup might work for a few images.

[image]

But if you have many images, you might want to turn them into an image sequence (just renaming them with the same name and progressive numbers will work). Then load the image sequence as a texture.

If what you want to do is have the image change with every frame of your scene use the default options and use autorefresh.

[image]

If you want to manually set the duration of each image. Set the number of frames and start frame to 1 and animate the offset value.

[image]

Note that by doing this the images will change from one frame to the next but will not dissolve gradually.