# Help with Texture fade out

Tags: modeling

I know how to add a material to a plane and then apply an *Image Texture* to that plane. I know how to make it appear in the *3D Viewport*, *Edit Mode*, and the final render.

I want a way to make one *Image Texture* fade into another one using purely material nodes. This should be able to be achieved via two keyframes that are visible in the *Timeline* or *Dope Sheet*. I have tried applying two textures to one material and two separate textures onto two separate materials, though I have found that I can't particularly assign two materials at once without scripting or the compositor. These are my questions, basically. They're fairly related, so I figured I'd ask them both at once.

- How can I set up an *Image Texture* to "fade off" (dissolve into a *Diffuse BSDF* or other blank material) in an animation render on a plane object?
- Second, how can I make an image fade transition, via two frame keys in an animation render without the compositor or scripting? Is this possible on precisely one plane or surface, or must I use two coinciding surfaces?

Comment: edit and post the text of your question here, put some effort in asking your question if you are serious about it and want an answer.

Comment: I am trying to get blender to do a colour or alpha "fade out" from one texture to another texture on the same object behind it.  However I can't insert prior and later key frames and get anything to animate.  I could I animate a fade out like this on only one object's material with two textures?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node setup at the bottom of the following images and keyframe the *Mix Shader's Fac:* value from 0-1. Obviously load one image into one node and another into the other node.

*Fac: at 0, notepad showing:*

[image]

*Fac: at 1, bricks showing:*

[image]

If you wish, the pictured .blend file with the nodes can be downloaded right here:

[image]

If you want to fade into a *Diffuse BSDF*, just don't include one of the *Image Textures* and still keyframe the same value.

*Fac: at 0, notepad showing:*

[image]

*Fac: at 1, Diffuse BSDF showing:*

[image]