# I have a folder of X number of textures, I wish to render the same image X number of times, once for each texture

Tags: texturing, scripting, pynodes

I have a model with the material set up, but I wish to change an image texture on this model for each frame. In the past I have set up an image texture node and mix shader for each texture but this is time consuming.

I wish to automate the process a little and have it so that blender sets the number of frames to be rendered to the number of textures / image files in any chosen folder and for it to load each texture for each frame.

I believe this should be doable in python but I am rather new to scripting in python. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [how do you animate image textures materials with keyframes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes)

Answer (score 2):

Use an image sequence as input for your *Image Texture* node then render an animation.

[image]

When clicking the folder button in the *Image Texture* node to browse for files make sure you tick the option *Detect Sequences* to the bottom left of the File Browser.

[image]

Pick all images in the folder and set them up as an animated texture sequence, adjust the sequence speed so it matches on picture per scene frame.

[image]

You will have to make sure your image files have consistent naming and identical file format, so Blender can detect them as a sequence. That means a base name similar across all files, plus a numbering scheme. Say something along the lines of `Base_File_####.extension`.

Comment: Thank you, this is a significant upgrade to what I was using before. Is there any way to modify the node that allows it to read every single image file in a single folder?

Comment: Why not just batch rename files? It is probably a lot easier, there are dozens of automated renaming utilities around.

Comment: Could you also show how to do this via code? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos