# How can I infinitely loop a png sequence in blender?

Tags: 2d, loop

Imagine I have a transparent png sequence of a bird flying that takes 1 second each loop.

How can I import the png sequence into Blender, and loop it infinitely in a way that I can then drag the bird around the stage, so that combined with the loop animation it will appear to be flying in the background as a transparent flat png image?

I want to combine 2D and 3D art.

Comment: You could [animate the offset of the image property](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36793/30849) or add an expression in the offset property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the images so that they have sequential numbers at the end of the name of the file. Enable the [`Images As Planes`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html) addon. In the add menu select add images as planes. Select the image sequence you want to import.

[image]

Click on the cogwheel icon on the right of the import menu to expand the options and select *Animate Image Sequence*, set the material to *Shadeless*, Check *Alpha* and set it to *Premultiplied*. Enable *Auto Refresh*.

[image]

A plane with the image mapped to it will appear. To make the image sequence loop endlessly, enable *Cyclic* on the material.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer!