# Repeat or loop Image Sequence in Video Edit

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image-sequence

I added an image sequence to the Video Editing. If I drag and increase it's size, then only the last picture is shown when the frame is outside usual bounds of the sequence. Is it possible to make it looping, repeated?? I tried all the settings, googled a lot, but found nothing helpful..

Comment: did you try select it, press shift-D and move it to the right? after you did that, you can press shift-R to repeat that

Comment: @Chris yes, I know have to make copies in Blender `:)` My question is about searching for a more robust way.

Comment: you can prevent such comments if you improve your question by adding things you tried or know... ;) that's why there is https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly possible as of Blender 3.6+. You have to manually duplicate it as many times as needed to fill the desired timeline duration. But fortunately, there is a workaround using the addon [`Images as Planes`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html) as described [in this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176479/how-can-i-infinitely-loop-a-png-sequnce-in-blender).

Comment: Hm, the addon description says about planes, materials, and it is used from the VIewPort, which sounds like usual modelling+animating, but the Q is about video editing 

Comment: it works i tried it. you just position your plane flat on the xy axis and then have your camera view from the top view so it's in 2D view like a video. and since it is "Shadeless" it won't get affected by light and still have the same result as in your video edit.

Comment: I mean, I have a project without 3D objects at all, with no scene rendering pipeline, only Video Editing tab to compose images, videos and music...

Comment: yeah unfortunately this is the only workaround, so since you can't use it, then it means you have to stick to `Shift+D` :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a speed control strip.  In the video editor, with your image sequence selected, shift-a -> effect strip -> speed control:

[image]

By default, a speed control strip is set to stretch the time of the strip it affects, by however the speed control strip is stretched.  But you want it to run cyclic, so we can use it on a different mode:

[image]

First, I stretched the base strip, the strip that the speed control strip modifies.  Then, I set the effect strip to "frame control" mode (see the sidebar on the video editor.)  I keyframed frame control value to 1 at frame 1, 77 at frame 77, set linear interpolation in the graph editor viewport, and then used a "make cyclic" operation in the graph editor.