# Object with multiple materials and multiple textures for color variation mechanic

Tags: texturing, materials

Hello :) I have an object, let's say a piece of cloth; I assigned a material to that object and a uv map_texture to that material. Now i want to assign another material with another texture to the whole piece of cloth, and maybe a third material with it's own texture. My intent is to export this object to unity with it's three materials each with it's own uv map_texture, so I can code and press certain button to make the object change materials (and textures), something like a color variation mechanic. In blender, when I add a second material to the object, and it's texture to that material, I can't paint that second texture without painting again on the first material. I don't know how to approach this problem, and im not sure im explaining it properly; I don't even know if what I plan to do can be done like that, it's just an idea that crossed my mind. My first approach was to save the object in 3 different files, each with it's own material and color, and just replace them in unity everytime i hit certain key, but my question is: can i do that same thing with just 1 file of the object and 3 different materials (and uv maps)? So I can put in the script: if you press X change the material of the object to the 2nd or 3rd. If so, how can I do it? Thank you very much, I'll also keep looking in more tutorials :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32382/is-it-possible-to-animate-textures?r=SearchResults&s=3|45.4121 about animating textures