# How can I smoothly transition between two UV maps?

Tags: uv

In the "UV Maps" section in Context, it is possible to switch between two different UV maps.

Map 1:

[image]

[image]

Map 2:

[image]

[image]

I would like to be able to transition smoothly between these two UV maps, so that I can animate the eyes moving smoothly.

How can I achieve a smooth transition between UV Maps?

Comment: Hi. This could be an 'XY problem': https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . It may be better to ask about animating the eyes smoothly and see what solutions you get, instead of asking about transitioning between UV Maps.

Comment: @RayMairlot Good point - you may be correct. I'd still like to know how to transition UV maps, however I will continue searching for different solutions for this specific problem.

Comment: check this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32382/is-it-possible-to-animate-textures

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm with Ray on this. It sounds like the wrong solution for the problem at hand.

Anyway, you can't really "change between" UV maps, but you can transition between them at shader level.

Since UVs are vectors like RGB values, you can work around it by using a *Color Mix* node to "mix" between two UV layers.

[image]

[UVWarp, or UV Project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap/57422#57422) may be more adequate solutions

Comment: Thank you, that's a great answer and I will also look into UVWarp.

With this solution, how would I change the factor value during keyframe animation?

Comment: You can keyframe the *Factor* value by pressing `i` over the slider like any other property. You can the tweak it from the *Graph Editor*

Answer (score 4):

*Didn't see the [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36785/30849) untill I wrote the answer, sorry.*

I'm [also] with Ray on this, it sounds like the wrong solution for the problem at hand.

If you want a smooth transition, you can animate a single UVMap with AnimAll.

Enable the builtin **AnimAll** addon.

[image: animall]

Setup up the first UV position and go to the first frame, then click on Insert in the AnimAll Keyframe menu.

Move to another frame, reposition the UV map and insert another AnimAll keyframe. The animation will playback in object mode.

[image: animated]

The created keyframes are using Blender keyframes system, even though it is not exposed for UV maps.

The keyframes are available in the Timeline, the Graph Editor and the Dopesheet.

[image: keyframes]