# How to animate face textures with images?

Tags: texturing

[image: Shader Editor]I want to animate a face texture after a character gets punched to change.
I have 3 images.
Here is the shader editor setup, I got the rig from someone else.

How would I do this?

Comment: There are plenty of suggestions on this site about [texture animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32382/111042).  Odd that you just didn't search for "animate texture"!  Find one where you can select one of three images based on a custom property setting (e.g. based on a "Punched Index").  I often use this to select a cloth pattern (e.g., "red or green underpants")

Comment: also check my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181389/how-can-i-animate-a-2d-face-rig-on-any-3d-object

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave you with my example of Shader nodes "image chooser" logic, here for hair texture (color) index based on a custom property.  I use a custom property at the object level (instead of the suitable material level) because of some problems with linked library overrides.

First I create the custom property that will be an index for hair color:

[image]

Then as an input to the Diffuse color, I use a group node called HairColor:

[image]

Inside this I supply the various texture images (think: your face punch images!) to a Chooser group node :

[image]

Inside the chooser group node (Hair Color Chooser), I use Mix nodes.  I first hover the mouse over the previously created custom property and right mouse click to the context menu, and select *Copy as New Driver*.   In the *Factor* property I right mouse context *Paste Driver*, and then edit the driver expression (another context menu item), to add the logic so that I get a cascading binary selection (A or B selection of the images).

[image]

It is unfortunate that there is not a multi-choice node (instead of just Mix Node with A through B inputs), which would reduce labor.

Here is my example to explore: [image]