# noise texture Projecting outward from center point

Tags: node-editor, shaders, texture-coordinates

While usinging shader nodes, I am trying to make a noise texture on a plane, start from the middle and project radially so when I shrink the necessary xyz, I can turn the noise into lines.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/how-to-create-a-procedural-chevron-like-texture-material/45169#45169

Comment: Unless im miss reading the content in the link, this does not answer my question. I gues when i say radially i mean a line coming from the center point towards all the edges

Comment: can you post a image example, even if it just a hand drawn sketch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a scalar multiple of cosine of the angle that the vector makes with the x axis to the x component, and similarly with the y component but with the sine of the angle, this will produce:

[image: Node Tree]

Higher scalar values means more line-like distortion. A radial distortion can be done as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to do, thank you.  But is there a way to move the texture around, I noticed it stays at 0,0,0 and its cool i can move the object around and goto dif parts of the texture.

Comment: Do i use a different geometry link. Or say I apply this to a cube, is there a way to center it on each face of a cube?

Comment: @NickSieben Did you try transforming the Position input using a mapping node or a vector math node?

Comment: I actually thought I did this but had my mapping node in the wrong spot. Thank you! This is great

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a wave texture, like in the first photo, except with lines starting sharply in the center. Ive tried multiple things and looking up the triangle wave but I dont understand the math well enough to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be really helpfull [How to Twist a Procedural Material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/78379/245)

I think the basic idea of the question is:
"When I scale a noise texture around x", I get "lines" along the yz-plane, can I transform the coordinate system in a way to get radial lines"

The "cheap" way of doing this is something like [image: this]
where a linear cut through the noise texture gets rotated around the center. For a more control, I think the coordinates need to be transformed into spherical ones and the angle needs to be scaled.

Comment: Using a quadratic gradient as the input vector for the noise will yield the same effect, but is generally faster and simpler.

Comment: Could you elaborate? When I don't take the square root, the scale increases depending on the distance to the origin. On the other hand the mesh is scaled to an 8 by 8 dimension, so at the default dimensions, the effect might be smaller.

Comment: I actually meant the distance. Check the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how i ended up here.

But i actually do this with a vector math node and texture coordinates

In Spherical mode:
[image]

and radial mode:
[image]

It's never too late!