# How can I make a radial noise gradient?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to create a bump map for an anisotropic metal cylinder. An answer on [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132218/noise-texture-projecting-outward-from-center-point) shows exactly what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

However, when I try recreate it, this is my result (I'm using a vector math node--which looks different, but I don't know of any other nodes that have "normalize"):

[image]

Can anyone help me figure this out? Cheers!

**UPDATE**: Thanks for the help! I combined the two answers, added a little flair, and got this:
[image]
[image]
P.S. For anyone trying to recreate this later: The bump distance is set to 0.0003

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just need to create this random circular output, you can actually just plug the gradient node's color output into a noise texture.

Note: Geometry -> Position is based on actual position in the scene, so that may not be what you want to use.  I'm using object coordinates here.

[image]

You can control where the effect terminates by using a mapping node.  By default gradient texture generates a 1m radius sphere.  The scale relationship is inversely proportional, so to extend it over an entire axis, you can set that axis to 0.

[image]

Increase the scale of the noise texture for finer rings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for going into so much detail and explaining your reason for using object coords. That clears up the main reason why I couldn't get it to work (the object I was using was not centered at the world origin). I combined your answer with the other and got the exact result I hoped to create. Cheers!

Comment: Great to hear, fantastic result.

Comment: Cheers. I couldn't have done it without your help ;)

Answer (score 7):

[*Vector Math*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/vector_math.html#vector-math-node)*>length* seems to work well here to accomplish your goal:

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

Adding a [*Math> Multiply node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/math.html#math-node) between the length and [noise texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html#noise-texture-node) will allow you to scale the rings as well as seen below:

[image]

---

Result:
[image]

You can take this a step further, for a little more control and use [*Vector Rotate*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/vector_rotate.html#vector-rotate-node) to help here. The *Math>Multiply* is what will control the size and direction (clockwise/ counter clockwise) of the rings.

The modified setup:

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

Here it is in action:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried using length, but I didn't realize the position variable of the geo node was based off relative position in space. This solution (mixed with the other), was exactly what I hoped to create! Cheers :)

Comment: welcome, for an in depth overview of texture coordinates and how they work in procedural textures have a look [at this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0) it's an old video, but not  at all outdated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll watch this while I eat lunch :)