# Wrap 2D image into 3D straw-like cylinder

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv-image-editor

I'm new to Blender and need some help from someone:
My problem: I have a 2D image that I need to wrap in a 3D straw-like object. The image should be spirally wrapped at an angle of 45 degrees.

Here is more detailed explanation of my problem:

From vector logo:
[image]

I want to make a custom designed drinking straw model:
[image]

Final product looks like this:
[image]

Now, I want to be able to make 3D model of a final product so that I can show it to my supervisor for inspection.

Hope that I explained my problem in more detailed manner this time.
**Big thanks to all the people who helped thus far in the comments!**

Comment: The image you've added to your question is much too small to see any details.

Comment: @JohnEason thanks for noticing, I've updated comment with bigger picture. Hope that works out.

Comment: Yes. It's visible now but we still need to see an image of what you are hoping to achieve and what problems you've had so far.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78379/how-to-twist-a-procedural-material

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Twist a Procedural Material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78379/how-to-twist-a-procedural-material)

Comment: How does your object look like? Maybe share your file (don't forget to pack your image)

Comment: @moonboots  
I've updated the question. Care to take another look at it? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cylinder, choose the front view, switch to *Edit* mode, unwrap with the *Cylinder Projection* option, give your object a material with the image selected in an *Image Texture* node, scale the UV on Y in the *UV Editor* so that it's at the right scale and proportion:

[image]

Rotate the UV 45°:

[image]