# Substance Designer Questions

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

Substance Designer I have heard about because of blender guru, I am a new blender user, I have quit before, but now I am more interested into blender. Substance Designer I heard was a bit popular the only problem is pricing it is a bit too expensive and I was hoping I could start somewhere that is free. If you could tell me anything related to Substance Designer that is free that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Blender whatsoever.

Comment: If you are trying to learn Blender, then watch some tutorials about texture painting. Its very similar to Substance and its FREE.

Answer (score 2):

Substance Designer is a primarily procedural texture generation program. It allows you to build all sorts of textures out of node graphs (and some image inputs if you want).

Guess what other program allows you to do this? Blender!
Blender doesn't have all the features and complex nodes that Substance has, but it is still very capable. 
You could start by looking at stuff like:

- [How to create our own procedural texture like the default ones in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90572/how-to-create-our-own-procedural-texture-like-the-default-ones-in-blender)
- https://cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/blender-cycles-tutorial-stonemarble-how-to-make-any-texture/