# How to make this texture/effect?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I noticed most swords have this cool wavy effect/texture on them:

[image]

I can't seem to replicate this in blender. I tried to make it with geometry but it really needs to be a texture. I'm not sure how to create this type of texture, what should I do?

Comment: if it's supposed to be a texture, unwrap your mesh, export the UV layout, and paint it in an image editor? In your picture it seems like there's no difference between the surfaces except color, so maybe it doesn't even need a bump or normal or specular map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: final_and_nodes]

You can create simple [Sine Function](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42731/creating-wisp-materials-in-cycles) which can be controllable (frequency, postion, width, amplitude) and position wave at the bottom of your model.

Take into account position in 3D space (rotation matter).

You can rotate your object and apply rotation or switch Z for Y in **Separate XYZ** node.

In this example I've used **Color Ramp** to control colour for **Roughness** input.

Bottom nodes are just for bump, so don't pay too much attention to them.

Comment: Wow man thank you for the answer, this definitely helped me. I had no idea this even really existed.