# how to make realtime motion blur or motion blur like effect/smear effect, for anime style animations in eevee on selected objects

Tags: animation, mesh, eevee-render-engine, motion-blur

I need help making real time motion blur like effects for my anime style animations. It also has to be on selected objects and on specific parts of a mesh, like the hands and feet. Is there a trick or add-on that can do this?

An example being when a character goes to punch only their fist or arm is blurred rather than their entire body.

I'm using blender 2.91 and the eevee render engine. I know motion blur is in eevee now but I need an effect that will only affect certain characters/ objects or certain body parts.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Anyone, at all?

Comment: Probably you get no answers or votes because the question is not clear. Use images as examples of what you want to get, and describe what you have tried that is not working.

Comment: Just did, and I haven't because I don't know where to start. The built-in motion effects all, unless there's a trick to focus it.

Comment: **You need to be more focused on your questions**. All of those examples are different kind of effects. Try using the search box at the top to find information. Some examples of similar questions on this site: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93921/how-to-add-trailing-light-effect-to-finger-tips and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42731/creating-wisp-materials-in-cycles?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Well I think it's called smear as its fake motion blur but its still a motion blur like effect. Also, I can't focus it as it's the same effect just utilized differently, also different art styles and mediums. Its kind of dumb to ask 2 questions for the same effect.

Comment: I know I am too late but I think this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1g2fSuVFs0&t=6s) will help