# Complex light trails as in God of war 3

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, light

How to make similar light trails as in 
https://youtu.be/IfW1xw2vD-Y?t=10 ?

I have made only in circle motion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2togAvQSr4

I don't know how to combine multiple ones. When one stops, the other light trail begins seamlessly.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles

Comment: Thanks @PaulGonet , that's what I want. I just need to figure it out how to combine multiple patterns of light trails in one combo.