# How to create a sword trail smear in Blender Internal with Particles?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I want to create a sword trail smear in Blender with Particles. I cannot figure it out, and googling doesn't seem to give me too much direction. Perhaps I'm googling incorrectly.

The sort of smear I'm talking about is this:

[image]

So far, I have gotten this far with mine:

https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/RequiredThirdBedbug

The issues I'm having are mainly:

- Emitter does not emit along the whole length of the emitter (which is a seperate object that follows the curvature of the sword).
- I cant figure out how to change the emission particles; theyre way to big, bright and white.
- I dont know how to set a minimum speed the sword must swing at to emit particles.

Comment: If you somehow decide to make this effect using a texture instead of particle system, here's a solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles