# How to make slash and shock wave effects for animations Blender Internal render

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, effects

I want to make slash effects for an animation i am working on i want the slash to be similar to the slash and shockwaves in the fate series.

https://youtu.be/P20KupJZ_W4?t=353

this should be a good example

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92715/how-to-create-a-sword-trail-smear-in-blender-internal-with-particles

Comment: 1st one is not gonna work as it has to work in blender internal render and the 2nd one likely is not asking for the same slash and not asking for shockwave effects at all,Plus it has not gotten an answer