Claw swing effect? How can I make this effect?
this is the animation made by Nammac.
https://objkt.com/tokens/hicetnunc/511008
When the monster swing his claw, the 3 line effects appearing and disappearing is quite cool. How can I achieve that with the black outlines(Freestyle or backfaceculing solidify modifier I guess)?
I've tried but failed

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93921/how-to-add-trailing-light-effect-to-finger-tips/94976#94976
