How can I achieve a glowing circular trail in blender cycles?
Can I please know how to make this circle glowing trail texture in blender cycles? Emission don't work they don't glow much and the edge is too visible


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24251/how-to-create-motion-trail-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=traIL

I just checked out the other related topics, but I think they’re not quite like what I want to achieve. Still, thank you for your response. I have a video example of the trail that I want to achieve, and I hope someone can help me solve this. Thanks.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTxcGYJAmmc&t=11s
